# I need help about a product

Tags: patent-infringement

I want to create a product and I want to know how I can get a patent for it.

Also I want to know this:

Some technologies are already patented.

Lets say I will do a doorbell system Smart doorbell.

I want to send a push notification or a message to the user when someone rings the bell. Somebody has already got the patent. So do I need to get permission from the user that I will use their patent in for my product.